# Scaling large div to fit flex container causes incorrect positioning

Tags: html, css, flexbox, transform, scale

The goal is to scale content to fit within a container.

When the content is smaller than the container, the transformation works and the content is centered.

However, if the content is too big, positioning breaks. The content no longer honors the CSS rules to remain centered.

The scale value `0.300648` is meant to fit the large content (3036x2162) within the parent (900x650).

Even a smaller scale value like `0.2` fails to center the content properly.

How to get the content to remain centered, regardless of the scale value?

To clarify, both the scale factor and absolute position of the content are required.

This JSFiddle shows the problem, with the red div representing the content (and not being centered): https://jsfiddle.net/panabee/bwpa3snk/10/

```
#previewBox {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 900px;
    height: 650px;
    border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.canvas-container {
  width: 3036px;
  height: 2162px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
  transform: scale(0.300648);
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 3036px;
  height: 2162px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: A bit difficult to debug without the HTML and content, but the code looks unnecessarily complex if your goal is to have a div with a div inside that fills the parent and inside that another div that fills that.

Comment: @H.W.Sanden Sorry forgot to include the JSFiddle. Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

Here the `content`'s scale will honor the size of its parent. I.e setting the scale to `scale(1)` would take up the parents entire container. Setting `scale(.5)` would take up half of the container, and remain the content-div centered. Please let me know if I didn't understand your question.

```css
      body {
        display: flex;
        height: 100vh;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      .canvas-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 1000px;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: yellow;
      }

      .content {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        transform: scale(0.5);
      }
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="canvas-container">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of variations, one with overflow hidden and scale(2), the other without scale. Added max-width and max height 100 % to the content and set width and height to 100 % for the container. Larger px inside smaller px usually creates trouble in my experience, so the max sizes counter that.

```css
#previewBox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 900px;
  height: 650px;
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* this prevents overflow since the scale is set to 2, it can also be set to auto to make it scrollable or removed entirely to get full overflow */
}

.canvas-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  user-select: none;
  transform: scale(2);
}

.content {
  background: red;
  width: 3036px;
  height: 2162px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="previewBox">
  <div class="canvas-container">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
#previewBox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 900px;
  height: 650px;
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.canvas-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  user-select: none;
  /* removed scale since the size matches the container anyway */
}

.content {
  background: red;
  width: 3036px;
  height: 2162px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="previewBox">
  <div class="canvas-container">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for this. however, we need the content to fit the parent container (900x650), which means we still need a transform scale to shrink the content. any ideas?

Comment: @crashalot The content div fits the parent in the second example. Are there any additional elements that should be in there?

Comment: If you're open to a small consulting role for questions like this, just sent you an email (from your website). There are more details. Either way, thanks for your help.

Comment: To clarify, I sent an email since posting a link to our website isn't allowed (spam).